# Django query set filtering, how to filter data on dynamic list

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-queryset, mongoengine

I am using django 1.10 and mongodb in backend. For mongodb I am using mongoengine 0.11.
In mongodb, I have collection named "test_coll", which contains fields "name","dept" and "tag". Sample data from collection is as follow-

```
name    dept    tag
peter   dev     k1
mark    tester  k1
sachin  dev     k1
amit    manager k1
```

I am providing list

```
dept_list=['dev','tester']
```

This list is dynamic.

Below is code from function

```
from mongoengine import Q
dept_list=['dev','tester']
output_list = []
query_dept objects = Q()
    for dl in dept_list:
        query_objects |= Q(dept__iexact=dl)            
    for details in test_coll.objects.filter(((Q(tag__iexact='k1')) & query_objects )):
       output_list.append({'name':details.name,'dept':details.dept,'tag':details.tag})
return output_list
```

As per list `dept_list=['dev','tester']`  and sample data provided above, I get details from collection where tag is 'k1' and dept are 'dev','tester'.

So I am stuck at, if I provide, `dept_list=['']` contains empty string then it should return all the data where tag='k1'. In my case it is not returning anything.
Can anyone provide solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when `dept_list = ['']`   then
I had to remove empty string from list
`dept_list = filter(lambda item: item != '', dept_list)`

modified code is as-

```
from mongoengine import Q
dept_list=['']
query_dept objects = Q()
for dl in dept_list:
    query_objects |= Q(dept__iexact=dl)            
for details in test_coll.objects.filter(((Q(tag__iexact='k1')) & query_objects )):
   output_list.append({'name':details.name,'dept':details.dept,'tag':details.tag})
return output_list
```

So this gives expected output.

Answer (score 0):

`''` is an item in dept_list: it doesn't mean **it is an empty list**. An empty list is `[]`. So, you should make a conditional where you check that if the listhas that item, don't do filtering, as there isn't any `dept` whose value is `''`. Or if the list has that item, pop it.

Actually, your SQL query looks like: `SELECT * FROM test_coll WHERE tag="k1" AND dept="";`. Making the change I just commented it would turn to `SELECT * FROM test_coll WHERE tag="k1";`.

Comment: Yeah. I have figured out. Thanks for help. :)